# Laravel TDD Failed asserting that an array has the key 'id'

Tags: php, laravel, tdd, phpunit, laravel-7

I've been following this [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbh8Ogl_QcI&list=PL3ZhWMazGi9KGG64X_HJlZ_sQuvyFGoMo&index=3) to catch up with TDD with Laravel. I'm getting

> Failed asserting that an array has the key 'id'.

error message when I run the test command.

Below is my code:

**api.php**

```
Route::namespace('API')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/products', 'ProductController@store');
});
```

**ProductController.php**

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use App\Product;
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $product =  Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'slug' => $request->slug,
            'price' => $request->price
        ]);
        return response()->json($product, 201);
    }
```

**ProductControllerTest.php**

```html
public function can_create_a_product()
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/products', [
            'name' => $name = $faker->company,
            'slug' => str_slug($name),
            'price' => $price = random_int(10, 100)
        ]);
        $response->assertJsonStructure([
            'id', 'name', 'slug', 'price', 'created_at'
        ])
        ->assertJson([
            'name' => $name,
            'slug' => str_slug($name),
            'price' => $price
        ])
        ->assertStatus(201);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('products', [
            'name' => $name,
            'slug' => str_slug($name),
            'price' => $price
        ]);
        
    }
```

Structure of products table:

```
id | image | name | price
```

The video series I'm following is made on laravel 5.7  and I'm running Laravel 7.
Is this the cause of error ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I need to use

`use RefreshDatabase;`

trait.